# Do applicants of first time child British Passports in the USA need countersignatures?

Tags: passport, uk-citizens, children

I've had a look at the [Government Site on overseas applications for the USA](https://www.gov.uk/overseas-passports/y/usa/applying/child/usa), and the [checklist for supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/342794/Supportingdocs1AUG2014.PDF) too. However over [here](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-child-passport/apply-for-a-child-passport), it says I need a countersignature.

The issue is I just got to the USA, so apart from my partner I don't know anyone for over 2 years (and she can't countersign it according to the list). It seems a big ambiguous, as on the stuff for foreign applications it doesn't mention countersignatures but on the website for applying for a child passport it does.

Comment: The [Countersigning passport photos](https://www.gov.uk/countersigning-passport-applications) lists the situations where countersigned photos are needed, and 1st Child Passport is one of those. It also talks about what to do if you're outside the UK, and the requirements for who can do it then, so I think it's very much still required

Answer (score 2):

In case of ambiguity in the countersignature rules, one can contact the HM Passport Office. You can contact them by phone or by using their [online form](https://eforms.homeoffice.gov.uk/outreach/Passport_Enquiries.ofml). Here is the phone information:

- Telephone: 0300 222 0000
- Textphone: 0300 222 0222
- Text Relay: 18001 0300 222 0000
- Monday to Friday, 8am to 8pm
- Saturday, Sunday and public holidays, 9am to 5:30pm